# Telerik NativeScript and Android Keystore and iOS keychain

Tags: android, ios, telerik, nativescript

Does anyone know if Telerik's NativeScript functions with the iOS Keychain and wherever Android would store an applications encryption certificates? Doing some research on cross-platform solutions and securely storing encryption certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting thing is that as long as the API has it; 
(i.e. Android: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html and iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) then you can access it via NativeScript.

At this moment (2015/04/25) only the basics are built cross-platform as this is a very new platform. 
They do not have any keychain code built for either platform.  However, with that said I just build a fully functional sqlite library (android side) in a couple days; once I understood how NativeScript interfaces with Android.    I am guessing it will take me a couple more days to do the iOS side.   Then my sqlite will be cross platform and I can code my apps to use much simpler code.   So if you have done any work on either platform; then creating the abstraction libraries that you need should not be very difficult.

Comment: So basically you just write your own module, if you will, that talks between the JavaScript and the native library? Your answer is helpful. I'll mark it correct, since you've addressed there is no keychain suttf at the moment, but I don't have enough rep to upvote.

Comment: Yep, you have to write your own module for anything beyond most the basics at the moment.     But if you are familiar with writing native code on the platform, then it is rather simple as the integration is pretty seamless.   For example in Java you would write:

Comment: For example on Android/Java you would write: "import "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase" then call the "openOrCreateDatabase(...)"   in JavaScript you just do "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(...).   So basically you are putting the entire name space in without any import statement to reference the function you need.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the further details. I'm actually pretty fluent in native code for iOS and Android but not so much JavaScript under my belt haha. So sounds like a bit of a gap for me to catch up on at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can sign your apps, see 
tns build android -h
tns build ios -h

Comment: My question was not about signing apps. I'm asking about securely storing certificates that you would use to encrypt and decrypt secure data on your application.